# How can i regard a page as volatile or predict the next time of a page's content modification?

Tags: memory, operating-system, virtual-machine

I'm running virtual machine, so all the system information i can get. How can I use them to detect a page or  revalant pages volatile? The result can be just a approximate volatile time of empirical conclusion. I want to use time series analysis to predict the next time of a page's content modification, is it possible and accurate? Are there any better methods? Thanks very much!

Comment: I've seen this for a while but the question remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer for pages inside a process as the question if related to the OS gets very complex.

You can use [VirtualQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx) and [VirtualQueryEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx)to determine the status of a given memory page. This includes if it is read only, guard page, DLL image section, writeable, etc. From these statuses you can infer the volatility of some pages.

All the read only pages can be assumed to be none-volatile. But that isn't strictly accurate since you can use [VirtualProtect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) to change the protection status of a page. And you can use [VirtualProtextEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx) to the same in a different application. So you'd need to re-check these.

What about the other pages? Any writeable page you're going to have to periodically check them. For example calculate a checksum and compare to previous checksum's to see if they've changed. And then record the time between changes.

You could use the NTDLL Function [NtQueryInformationProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx) with **ProcessWorkingSetWatch** to get data on the page faults for the system.

Note sure if this what you're looking for but it's the simplest approach I can think of. It's potentially a bit CPU hungry. And reading each page regularly to calculate the checksums will trash your cache.